# Use Jump Menu to filter view

Tags: views, 7

I am trying to attach a Jump Menu to a view, which is a list of users. I would like the Jump Menu to act as a filter for the view.

I've gotten the Jump Menu to do that, but for some reason only when the filters for the fields it uses, are exposed. This is visually confusing (you can filter the same thing with the jump menu and the exposed filters). When the filters aren't exposed, the Jump Menu does nothing.

Does anyone have any ideas as to why this happens?

Thanks!

Jill

Comment: you say `I would like the Jump Menu to act as a filter for the view.` --  jump menus normally take you somewhere when you make a selection... how can a jump menu act as a view filter?

Comment: @longboardnode If you add the jump menu as an "attachment" (when editing the view, choose "Add Attachment"), and create a custom field that will be the url of the filtered list (eg www.example.com/people?filter=some_selection_from_jump_menu), then you can create a jump menu that will filter your view.

Comment: If you mean a dropdown select box with taxonomy terms that filters your view, you can just use [Better Exposed Filters](https://www.drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters) to do this easily and with Ajax. If you need to reload the page, then [this](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/79593/views-with-both-menu-and-jump-menu-taxonomy-terms-as-contextual-filters?rq=1) might help.